# I want my code to ask for a specific value from a column that is stored in a database

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
class quizmodel extends CI_Model {

    public function getQuestions()
    {
        $this->db->select("quizID, question, choice1, choice2, choice3, answer, subject");
        $this->db->from("quiz");
        $this->db->where?????


        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();

        $num_data_returned = $query->num_rows;

        if ($num_data_returned < 1) {
          echo "There is no data in the database";
          exit();   
        }
    }
```

This is my code, i want it so that the 'subject' field only asks for 'computing'. Or 'quizID' asks for quizID from 1 to 10.

Comment: Please read this document fully. You will your answers: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `quizID` 1-10 range, then you can use range like:

```
$this->db->where('quizID >=', 1);
$this->db->where('quizID <=', 10);
```

Or,

```
$this->db->where("quizID BETWEEN 1 AND 10");
```

If, you want to get only `computing` related data then you can use `LIKE` here:

```
$this->db->like('subject', 'computing');
```

Some additional and useful information:

```
$this->db->like('subject', 'computing', 'before');    // Produces: WHERE `subject` LIKE '%computing'
$this->db->like('subject', 'computing', 'after');     // Produces: WHERE `subject` LIKE 'computing%'
$this->db->like('subject', 'computing', 'none');      // Produces: WHERE `subject` LIKE 'computing'
$this->db->like('subject', 'computing', 'both');      // Produces: WHERE `subject` LIKE '%computing%'
```